# Extract date from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to download adjusted close prices and their corresponding dates from yahoo, but I can't seem to figure out how to get dates from `pandas DataFrame`.

I was reading an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433076/download-history-stock-prices-automatically-from-yahoo-finance-in-python/12433236#12433236)

```
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
from datetime import datetime
goog = DataReader("GOOG",  "yahoo", datetime(2000,1,1), datetime(2012,1,1))
print goog["Adj Close"]
```

and this part works fine; however, I need to extract the dates that correspond to the prices.

For example:

```
adj_close = np.array(goog["Adj Close"])
```

Gives me a 1-D array of adjusted closing prices, I am looking for 1-D array of dates, such that:

```
date = # what do I do?
```

`adj_close[0]` corresponds to `date[0]`

When I do:

```
>>> goog.keys()
Index([Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, Adj Close], dtype=object)
```

I see that none of the keys will give me anything similar to the date, but I think there has to be a way to create an array of dates. What am I missing?

Comment: In this case the dates are your index labels. You can access them with `goog.index`. Since it's time series data the datas are store as a [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it by `goog.index` which is stored as a DateTimeIndex.
To get a series of date, you can do

```
goog.reset_index()['Date']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.data import DataReader

symbols_list = ['GOOG','IBM']
d = {}
for ticker in symbols_list:
    d[ticker] = DataReader(ticker, "yahoo", '2014-01-01')
pan = pd.Panel(d)
df_adj_close = pan.minor_xs('Adj Close') #also use 'Open','High','Low','Adj Close' and 'Volume'

#the dates of the adjusted closes from the dataframe containing adjusted closes on multiple stocks
df_adj_close.index

# create a dataframe that has data on only one stock symbol
df_individual = pan.get('GOOG')

# the dates from the dataframe of just 'GOOG' data
df_individual.index
```