# Stock Quotes from Yahoo finance for Indian NSE, BSE

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-finance, stockquotes

Following is my query using YQL, data is fetched using Yahoo finance, I am using the symbols for the stocks traded on the Indian NSE, BSE

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select  * from yahoo.finance.quotes where 
symbol in ("AIAENG.NS","ATULAUTO.NS")&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env&format=json
```

Strange thing is this query always return null data (Invalid data) for all the fields, even when the symbol that I am using is correct and can be used on the Yahoo finance for querying the details. In fact same is for  another Indian exchange BSE, with respective symbols AIAENG.BO, ATULAUTO.BO

However if I replace the with US Nasdaq symbols like "YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT", it works without an issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download history stock prices automatically from yahoo finance in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433076/download-history-stock-prices-automatically-from-yahoo-finance-in-python)

Answer (score 8):

If someone's still looking out, and not satisfied with *nsetools* (because lack of historical data), here is the latest link I found to be working:

https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/CDSL.NS

Replace *CDSL* with appropriate symbol.

Comment: Hello, this still doesn't give the useful ratios such as PE or PB as `yfinance` does . Any alternatives ?

Comment: can you provide bse stock prices api also

Answer (score 6):

If yahoo finance is not your compulsion, then you can use this project.

http://nsetools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

This is well documented and uses NSE as a data source which is most reliable.

Comment: thanks, I am not tied to Yahoo, my requirement is for a 
C# program, which consumes the Json data and use it update an excel sheet of my stick holding. Currently I am using Google Finance, but that's not quite reliable. For using your Python utility, I need to  figure out if I can call it from my C# program, as I have never worked with Python. Please let me know if you have some idea

Comment: Honestly speaking even I don't know how to call a python program in a c  environment. In worst case I would suggest it to write a shell based program using the python utility and then call it through the c. I think c can easily call she'll based programs. But I feel that there must be more elegant way to achieve this.

Comment: Huh? If you can run a shell then you can run Python.

Comment: it doesn't give historic data

Answer (score 0):

Late in the game but adding my response just in case if anybody looking for an easiest way to get the near real time quote(up to 10 tickers) by using Google Finance REST call.

http://finance.google.com/finance/info?q=NSE:AIAENG,NSE:ATULAUTO

And the acronym description can be found here 
http://qsb-mac-plugins.googlecode.com/svn-history/r4/trunk/stock-quoter/trunk/StockQuoter.py

Comment: How would i know name of symbols other stocks? In your example it is AIAENG and ATULAUTO...can you please help?

Comment: You can use this url: https://www.google.com/finance/match?matchtype=matchall&q=dab