# How to get all Ticker symbols and its stock prices(csv format) using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stock-data

I wanted all ticker symbols and its stock prices in csv format.

expected output:

[image]

Is there any solution to get all data in csv?

[Download history stock prices automatically from yahoo finance in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433076/download-history-stock-prices-automatically-from-yahoo-finance-in-python)

using this approach we can get data related to one symbol only.

Or using `pandas_datareader` we have to pass SYMBOL as a input:

`panel_data = web.DataReader('SPY', 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)`

Is there any way to get all Ticker symbols and its related stock data using python ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using plextock for this:

**CSV report of all listed stocks:**

https://plextock.com/us-symbols?utm_source=so

**CSV report of key metrics (High, Low and Price are included there):**

https://plextock.com/key-metrics?utm_source=so